# Calculated Member based on dimension attribute value

Tags: mdx, dimension, ssas-2008

I want to make some Calculated Measures in my cube that conditionally use a value from the measure table, based on a dimension attribute value.

For example: where Document Status in the Document dimension is CP, use the Committed Value measure.  This is what I have for that:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].CalcCommittedValue
 AS ([Document].[Document Status].&[CP], [Measures].[Committed Value]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0;-$#,##0", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Document Total'  ;
```

And it looks like it works, until I start browsing the cube and put Document Status and CalcCommittedValue into the Browser.  All the options for Document Status display the same CalcCommittedValue.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you expect to be different from the result you see? The expression you use instructs Analysis Services to use the `CP` document status for determining the result, no matter what the document status of the cell is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I clearly have a lot to learn about MDX.  I'll be ordering a book on the topic shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this correctly, try using the SCOPE() statement...for example

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[CalcCommittedValue]
AS

  SCOPE([Document].[Document Status].[&CP]);

   THIS = [Measures].[Committed Value];

  END SCOPE;
```

The Scope statement will cause the value to be calculated whenever the Document Status of [CP] is present, and not otherwise. Very powerful statement, and should get you want you need.

Comment: Thanks Josh, this is what I ended up with, and so far, so good:

    CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[CalcCommittedValue]
      AS 0, 
    FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0;-$#,##0", 
    VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Document Total'  ; 
    
    Scope [Measures].[CalcCommittedValue];
      Scope [Document].[Document Status].&[CP];
        This = [Measures].[Committed Value];
      End Scope;
      Scope [Document].[Document Status].[All];
        This = ([Document].[Document Status].&[CP], [Measures].[Committed Value]);
      End Scope;
    End Scope;

Comment: I found more here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d3462d8d-2434-434a-acfa-3f6342a98084/new-calculated-member-based-on-existing-measure-and-a-dimension-value